# Android exiting from other screen orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, orientation

I have MainActivity. I start new Activity from it.
Then in that new activity I have layout and layout-land file. I have a close button and a handler of it which performs finish() method. If I open the app and press the close button everything is ok. If I open the app, change the orientation and press the close button, I see closing the activity (very quickily) and then it opens again. If I press close button second time, it closes the activity. How to handle this? How can I close the activity after changing the screen orientation? Thank you!

After closing orientation by finish() method in the horizontal orientation, this activity appears again in the vertical one

Comment: Please don't put a close button in an Android app.  It's is against all principles of Android and mobile app design.  That said, please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve and show the code for your onCreate, onResume and onPause methods and the click listener for the button.  Please don't post all of your code, we just need the relevant bits.

Comment: No, Close button doesn't close the app, it closes the activity. So, I want to close the activity, it performs:
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
And it works! But if I change the orientation, it works only after 2 clicking on the button...

Answer (score -1):

When you change the orientation it kills the app and restarts it. You need to just wait another split second. It will close then.

Comment: " it kills the app". No it doesn't.  The Activity is destroyed (and recreated), the app is not.  "You just need to wait" - in an event driven mobile operating system?